# ASP.NET Identity retrieving and editing user data inside the Manage View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I've got an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. When you login you can click on the link that says "Hello,  !" and you can see the Manage View, which is a default page made by the template, which uses the IndexViewModel.

I succesfully made it show the user's email by adding

```
public string Email { get; set; }
```

in IndexViewModel and then in the ManageController

```
var model = new IndexViewModel          
{
    HasPassword = HasPassword(),
    PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
    TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
    Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
    BrowserRemembered = await  AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId),
    Email = await UserManager.GetEmailAsync(userId)           
};
```

However this was easy, as the UserManager already has a Task called GetEmailAsync. How can I retrieve data from the database like this but for the rest of the fields I've added? (Users are being created by the RegisterStudentViewModel)
I've tried to create another Task but it didn't work. How would I go about solving this problem? I want them to be able to see their details and even edit them (such like changing of the Phone Number that already exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the entire user entity as follows:

```
var user = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
```

From there, you can do what you please with the user.

Alternatively, use `FindById(userId)`:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(userId);
```

Comment: @BudaCristian My pleasure.

Comment: I am having trouble creating an edit field like the template has a phone number one. There is an AddPhoneNumber Controller and ModelView and also a View, and I have created these but for Email but I do not understand how to change it and then save it so it changes the database entry as well?

Comment: @Buda. Open a new SO question for this issue. Feel free to link it here.